# Asana get /events

Tags: asana-api

everyone!

I've got a problem with receiving data for request like "/events" (as described in https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/events). I sent GET request to https:/ /app.asana.com:443/api/1.0/events/ and got error 400 (bad request).  For further information please see folowing details (token has been obfuscated)

Request:
GET /api/1.0/events/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 0/00000000000000000000000000000000
Host: app.asana.com

Response:
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    Server: nginx
    Date: Mon, 01 Feb 2016 10:01:43 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Asana-Content-String-Length: 215
    Pragma: no-cache
    Set-Cookie: TooBusyRedirectCount=0
    Cache-Control: no-store
    X-Asana-Preferred-Release-Revision: 20160130_055457_72a36bb0a264503a3e39ecea630b93bfff45340f
    X-Robots-Tag: none

Response body:
    d7
    {"errors":[{"message":"resource: Missing input","help":"For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"}]}

Could you please advice me a solution to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you are missing the resource input.

Please consult https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/events to see how to use this feature.